# Issue with "==" operator in a class

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am having an issue with my code in the `class room`. Whenever I try to have the room constructor (shown below) put a character in the array `ARoom` and `ADisc` and it is the same character as the one I am trying to ignore using `break` all values get ignored when I use `APrint()`.

```
room::room(int Si, int Sd)
{
    //makes ADisc and ARoom blank

    for(int d=1; d<=25; d++)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=78; i++)
        {
            this->SetSpot(i,d, char(0), "0");
        }
    }
    //this makes some filled
    for(int i=1; i<=Si; i++)
    {
        for(int d=1; d<=Sd; d++)
        {
            this->SetSpot(i,d, ' ', "0");
        }
    }
}
```

SetSpot()

```
void SetSpot(int i, int d, char ch, string disc)
{
    int Ni = i-1;
    int Nd = d-1;
    this->ARoom[Nd][Ni]=ch;
    this->ADisc[Nd][Ni]=disc;
}
```

Aprint()

```
void Aprint()
{
    system("CLS");
    for(int d=0; d<25; d++)
    {
    if(this->ARoom[d][0]==char(0))
        break;
    cout << "[";
        for(int i=0; i<78; i++)
        {
            if(this->ARoom[i][d]==char(0))
                break;
            cout << this->ARoom[d][i];
        }
    cout << "]" << endl;
    }
    int r = 0;
    for(int d=0; d<25; d++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<78; i++)
        {
            if(this->ADisc[d][i]=="0")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                r++;
                cout << "[" << r << "," << this->ARoom[d][i] << "]: " << this->ADisc[d][i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main()

```
int main()
{
    room Spawn(10,10);
    Spawn.SetSpot(5,1, char(1), "me");
    Spawn.SetSpot(4,1, char(2), "you");
    Spawn.Aprint();
}
```

Returns

```
[   ☻☺     ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.039 s
Press any key to continue.
```

If I change `if(this->ADisc[d][i]=="0")` to `if(this->ADisc[d][i]=="me")` then I get this

```
[   ☻☺     ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[1, ]: 0
[2, ]: 0
[3, ]: 0
[4,☻]: you
[5, ]: 0
[6, ]: 0
[7, ]: 0
[8, ]: 0
[9, ]: 0
[10, ]: 0
[11, ]: 0
[12, ]: 0
[13, ]: 0
[14, ]: 0
[15, ]: 0
```

It contiues to `[1876, ]: 0` but does not print `[3,☺]: me`.
How do I fix this or get around it?

Comment: how are ARoom and ADisc defined?

Comment: @hmatar `char ARoom[25][78];` and `string ADisc[25][78];` bolth are private.

Comment: @JasonLang using "me" was a test to find out what the error exactly was if I made all of the `ADisc` x and told it to ignore x then it will ignore everything but if I set all of `ADisc` to y and told it to ignore x it would ignore x like it should. The `break` is only needed to break the first loop otherwise I would have 2 `break`s

Comment: I'm not following your problem, or you're not following what I'm saying. The 'break' cancels the for loop, so it skips the check for everything else on the same row. Don't use a break, simple fix.

Comment: in fact, the check for me is breaking everything else on the same row.  25 * 78 = 1950, not 1876. So everything after "me" on that row is also being skipped, which is an error caused by using "break" here, it's jut less noticeable, because it only affects that one row. It's still an error. The amount of prints should by 1949 when ignoring the character "me".

Comment: @JasonLang then the question is why does `"me"=="0"` become `true`.

Comment: you're not making any sense now. I explained why you're getting the output you are getting.

Comment: when you BREAK on seeing "0", it's skipping the entire row, so it never even checks "me" at all. It just skipped to the NEXT row without checking any of that row.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your issue is with the use of "break". "break" is a command which breaks out of the current looping construct.

When you searched for "0" (empty tile), it called break as soon as it saw an empty, canceling the rest of the prints for that entire row.

When you searched for "me" (player tile?) it called break on seeing a "me" tile, skipping the print of the "me" tile and canceling the printing of the rest of that row, so any row without a "me" on it was fine.

So just getting rid of break here prevents that problem.

~~~

However, you mentioned that it's not printing the character you're trying to ignore, but the problem is that your if-statement is explicitly telling it *not* to print the tile information in those circumstances, so it's hard to know what your intended behavior is here. Maybe you can try without the if statement and let us know if there are any remaining issues.

Comment: The fact is that when it sees `0` to break but when it sees `me` it breaks anyways. The intention is when it sees `0` to break and when it sees something else (x) to print `[1,x]: x`. The other reported issue was that if I tell it to break when it sees `me` it breaks like it should.

Comment: What do you think "break" is doing?

Comment: You're not making any sense here. seeing a break is cancelling all other checks that exist on the same row of your grid.

Comment: break ends the for loop for the entire row. If you want to skip just "me" then it should in fact print 1949 rows of data (78 * 25 - 1). But you're only getting 1876, because the rest of the tiles on the same row as "me" got skipped. That still an error.